# POST request fails after successful login

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

There's not much to explain here. I've setup express and passport in a way that I think should work, and when I login with the correct information these are the outputs in the console:

```
Login attempt: mail@gmail.com
Login success: mail@gmail.com
Serialize:
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 5320883fbb3e62fc14fda44a,
  email: 'mail@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$10$VpTLJgwALxcTeNO1YH3k7eBXoI589fOZLzqtkSdpwL2N9sxPgO1bS',
  verified: true }
POST /login 404 714ms
```

Now, this is all of the relevant code:

```
import os = require("os");
import express = require("express");
import paths = require("./paths");
import https = require("https");
import http = require("http");
import fs = require("fs");
var stylus = require("stylus"),
    nib = require("nib");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");

var db = require("./db");
var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password"
    },
    function (email, password, done) {
        db.User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
            console.log("Login attempt: " + email);
            if (err) { return done(err); };
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect email" });
            }
            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
            }
            console.log("Login success: " + email);
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log("Serialize: ");
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    db.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log("Deserialize: " + err + ", " + user);
        done(err, user);
    });
});

var httpPort = 8442;
var httpsPort = 8443;

app.locals.pathNoProtocol = (os.hostname() == "domain.me" ? "domain.me" : "localhost") + ":" + httpsPort + app.path();
app.locals.path = "https://" + app.locals.pathNoProtocol;
app.locals.capitalize = function (str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
};

//Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure) { //HTTP request
        console.log("HTTP request for " + req.url + ". Redirecting to " + app.locals.path + req.url);
        return res.redirect(app.locals.path + req.url);
    }
    next();
});

app.enable("strict routing");

var compile = function (str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .use(nib());
};

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(stylus.middleware({ 
    src: __dirname + '/public', 
    compile: compile
}));
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "supersecret" }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});

paths(app); //Process paths

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");
mongoose.connection.on("connected", function () { console.log("Connected to db"); });

https.createServer({
key: fs.readFileSync("server-key.pem"),
cert: fs.readFileSync("server-cert.pem")
}, app).listen(httpsPort);

http.createServer(app).listen(httpPort);
```

I've left in some of the redirection stuff because I don't know, that may be the issue here.

Here's also how I handle the paths in paths.js

```
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    res.render("pages/login");
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
        succesRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/loginFailed"
    }
));
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone took the time to look over what I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It appears I have solved the problem. I'm tempted to leave the question here as a puzzle but it's probably a better idea to close it.
The mistake is in the app.post. successRedirect typo...